# How to change a server's index of/ page

Tags: php, html, apache

When an apache server is running, the http://localhost/~User/ lists the files in the server with a big Index of/ on the page.

I don't know what's the name for this page, but once I put an index.html(or a index.php), the page won't show anymore.

My questions are:

1. How do I view the listing page with an index file in it?
2. Is it possible to only show some of the directories/files on the listing page? (If not possible, what is the best practice to redirect?)
3. How do I disable the listing page, so it's secure for public access?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Listings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Listings) has all the answers you need.

**How do I view the listing page with an index file in it?**

You can change the index page so that it won't auto-load the index. `DirectoryIndex tmp-index.html` See: [Directory Listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Indexes)

**Is it possible to only show some of the directories/files on the listing page? (If not possible, what is the best practice to redirect?)**

Yes, by using `IndexIgnore` in your configuration file. See: [Excluding files](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Excluding_Files)

**How do I disable the listing page, so it's secure for public access?**

With the `Options` directive `Options -Indexes`. See: [Directory Listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Listings)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I view the listing page with an index file in it?

You don't. [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) only generates a listing if you don't have an index file.

> Is it possible to only show some of the directories/files on the listing page?

Don't turn on `ShowForbidden` and ensure the files will return FORBIDDEN responses or use the [`IndexIgnore` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore).

> (If not possible, what is the best practice to redirect?)

Probably [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), but it depends on exactly what you want to redirect from and to.

> How do I disable the listing page, so it's secure for public access?

Put an index file there, or turn off the `Indexes` [`Option`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options).